# getting rid of spaces in R column values using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data listing Postcodes:

```
   Postcode easting northing
1  AB1 1AA  394251   806376
2  AB1 1AB  394235   806529
3  AB1 1AF  394181   806429
4  AB1 1AG  394251   806376
5  AB1 1AH  394371   806359
```

I want to get rid of all the spaces in the Postcode column by doing this:

```
library(dplyr)
postcodes %>% mutate(Postcode = gsub(" ", "", Postcode))
```

But the it doesn't appear to work on my data.frame. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

I can do it in base R through:

```
  postcodes$Postcode <- gsub(" ", "", postcodes$Postcode)
```

But want a solution in dplyr

Comment: Your code works find for me. Remember that these dplyr functions return NEW dataframes, they do not re-write old ones.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't work for you?  If you want to change on execution, try `%<>%` from `magrittr` i.e `postcodes %<>% mutate(Postcode = gsub(' ', '', Postcode))`

Comment: ah, that might be it then! Sorry about that

Comment: postcodes <- postcodes %>% mutate(Postcode = gsub(" ", "", Postcode))Do you fancy adding it as an answer and I'll tick it